# If I save a dataframe within a dataframe, export it to a csv, and then reload it with pandas, will I still be able to access the inner dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe, and one cell within that dataframe contains another dataframe. What format, if any, can I save my dataframe to so that when I reopen it, I can access the dataframe that is in a cell of the outer dataframe?

Comment: A CSV is two-dimensional, so this likely won't work the way you seem to be conceptualizing it. Why not just try it and see?

Comment: Tried pickle format to save df ?